# Mint Uefi installation

Tags: linux, grub, linux-mint, efi

I got few small issues with a Mint installation. I've bought a new laptop (Asus n56vj) with a preinstalled Windows 8 system. And there is the first problem, laptop has uefi mode on. So when I try to boot a live cd, it fails. I need to turn on "legacy mode" and than I can boot from a live cd. But there is the second problem, when I restart laptop after installation of Mint, the system says there is no bootable media found. When I switch mode back to the UEFI, the Windows is run.

Is there a way for Mint to install EFI grub or something like that?
All guidances about this problem are welcome!

Thank you in advance,
Matej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-examine your firmware options to locate one to disable Secure Boot mode *without* enabling legacy/BIOS/CSM boot mode. You should then be able to re-install Mint *in EFI mode* to co-exist with Windows. (Alternatively, you could disable Secure Boot and then [install an EFI-mode boot loader,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) but that will probably be harder than re-installing Mint.)